# mysql query within PDO on loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

basically, I have a PDO form an old developer and I need to run a switch statment inside it to swap out values but my  loop fails every time, i've tried a standard mysqli query, fetch array etc and it doesn't work.. I'm new to PDO, any ideas how I can make the query run or build in a switch statement to compare the values?

```
private function loadNineFixedData( $filepath, $table ){

    //We are going to insert some data into the users table
    $sth = $this->dbcon->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO " . $table . "(cli, date, time, destination, dialled, duration, cost, destcode, extention, product, rate) 
                            VALUES (:cli, :date, :time, :destination, :dialled, :duration, :cost, :destcode, :extention, :product, :rate)"
    );
    $dest = $this->$dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM calltypes_nine where name = ? ");
    $dest->bindParam(":name", $description);
    $csv = \League\Csv\Reader::createFromPath( $filepath );



//now back to the csv reader to kick us off
$nbInsert = $csv->each(function ($row) use (&$sth) {

            $description = $row[11];

            $dest->execute();
            while($codes = $dest->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
                $code = $codes['destination'];
            }

        $cli = '0'.substr($row[2], 3);
        $time = str_replace(':','', $row[6]);
        $dialled = '0'.substr($row[3], 3);

             switch($row[11]){
                    case 'Standard':
                        $rate = 'STD';
                        break;
                    case 'Economy';
                        $rate = 'EVE';
                        break;
                    case 'Weekend':
                        $rate = 'WKD';
                        break;
              }
              switch ($row[1]) {
                    case 'N':
                        $prod = 'IICS';
                        break;

                    default:
                        $prod = 'VOCE';
                        break;

    //Do not forget to validate your data before inserting it in your database
    $sth->bindValue(':cli', $cli, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':date', $row[4], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':time', $time, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':destination', $row[9], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':dialled', $dialled, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':duration', $row[6], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':cost', $row[12], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':destcode', $code, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':extention', $row[14], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':product', $prod, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':rate', $rate, \PDO::PARAM_STR);

    return $sth->execute(); //if the function return false then the iteration will stop
    });        

 }
```

Comment: isn't it the `$dest` request that always fail? i think it should be `"SELECT * FROM calltypes_nine where name = :name "` because you bind the parameter explicitly

Comment: it is $dest that is killing it, but binding the paramater didn't fix it, is it becuase it's already within another loop under another prepared statement??

Comment: i don't think so, you should be able to prepare different requests at the same time, as long as you use different variables ( `$sth` != `$dest` ). What is the SQL error you get when trying the code?